# Why are Video.js controls showing weirdly?

Tags: javascript, css, video.js

My video.js controls are not showing in the video but outside the video with lot's of unnecessary options as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: controls]

My code is like this:

```
{% block content%}
<style>
  #video-js {
   max-width:auto;
   width:auto;
   max-height:auto;
   height:auto;
   margin:auto;
   padding:auto;
   background-color: #343A40;
}
</style>


  <video
    id="video-js"
    class="video-js vjs-custom-skin"
    controls
    preload="auto"
    width=""
    height=""
    data-setup=""
    autoplay

  >
    <source src="http://url.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
    <source src="http://url.flv" type="video/x-flv" />
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
      web browser that
      <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank"
        >supports HTML5 video</a
      >
    </p>
  </video>


<br>
<br>
  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.10.2/video.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/browse/@videojs/http-streaming@2.6.0/dist/videojs-http-streaming.js"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

How can I have these weird controls be gone and just have normal in video controls like play, pause, mute, volume up/down.

Comment: Styles should go into the `<head>`.

Comment: Not that it helps to solve the issue unfortunately

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem. Do you have some css that might overwrite the video styling? What does the rest of your html look like?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Video.js styles, https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.10.2/video-js.css

Also, while it's not the cause of the problem, including http-streamimg is redundant. It's included in Video.js 7+.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the Video.js styles mentioned above, you
should then be able to eliminate, re-arrange controls and tweak coloring,
by adding lines like these:

```
       <!--   Change ordering "current-time / duration" to appear on control-bar: -->
        <!--   See:    https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/2507  -->
        <style>
        .video-js   .vjs-current-time { display: block; }
        .video-js   .vjs-time-divider { display: block; }
        .video-js   .vjs-duration { display: block; }   
        .video-js   .vjs-remaining-time { display: none; }
        
        .video-js   .vjs-load-progress{display: inline-block; background: PaleGreen; height: 8px; width:100%; }
        .video-js   .vjs-play-progress{display: inline-block; background: LightCoral;     height: 8px; width:100%;}
        
        .video-js   .vjs-picture-in-picture-control { display: none; }

        # (These with leading "#" sign are 'commented-out'...are present here just so the NAMES of various entities are avail for experimenting.)
        #.video-js   .vjs-progress-holder { margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; background: Blue; }
        #.video-js   .vjs-loading-spinner{display: block;}
        #.video-js  .vjs-progress-holder  .vjs-play-progress { display: none; }
        </style>

    Hope these help...
```